# python3: json data changed slightly after being read

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have some json data from webscraping twitter, opening json in notepad++ shows this example key value pair:

```
"id_str": "823962574509248514",
```

but after reading in the json (i had two ways below):

```
filename = "../TheTweets/data/short.json"
columnName = ['id_str','created_at', 'full_text','in_reply_to_status_id']
data = pd.read_json(filename, orient=columnName)
#data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(filename, orient=columnName,encoding="utf-8"),columns=columnName)
```

i noticed that the id_str number changed:

```
"id_str":823962574509248512, (looks like the last number)
```

after running print(data.dtypes), i see that id_str is int64

I don't quite understand what is going on, and it seems quite a big issue if the ids don't match anymore (i go on to save the data back into a new json, and compare in notepad++). I can't quite tell what the impact of this is if i have thousands of rows

Comment: It's strange the value change but specially the type change from string to numeric !

Comment: @Indent i was thinking to look into how to specify dtypes during read_json process

Comment: Have you tried `json_normalize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug (don't quote me on that), with `pd.read_json` implicitly converting the strings to integers, which shouldn't be happening. You could try forcing the `dtype` and preventing the conversion from happening.

This is what is currently happening for you:

```
In [107]: j
Out[107]: '{"id_str":{"0":"823962574509248514"}}'

In [108]: pd.read_json(j)
Out[108]: 
               id_str
0  823962574509248512
```

Now, pass in a `dtype` argument to `read_json` and see the difference:

```
In [109]: pd.read_json(j, dtype={'id_str' : str})
Out[109]: 
               id_str
0  823962574509248514   # note the difference in the last digit

In [110]: _.dtypes
Out[110]: 
id_str    object
dtype: object
```

If you want to coerce multiple columns, add more key-values to the `dtype` dictionary. If you want *everything* as a string, `dtype=str` will do.

---

Well, this is promising. Given your sample data, `json_normalize` would seem like the way to go here.

```
In [132]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(json.loads(data))
Out[132]: 
                       created_at  \
0  Tue Jan 24 18:36:00 +0000 2017   

                                           full_text              id_str  \
0  @ABC Can I send a DM, I've emailed twice and g...  823962574509248514   

  in_reply_to_status_id  
0                  None
```

Note that `id_str` *also* works. In your case, you'd need to call `json.load` on your file and pass *that* to the function.

Comment: i added data = pd.read_json(filename, orient=columnName,dtype=str),
and it seems to have resolved the issue and at the same time introduced another. as part of processing i save data into two different jsons, both the same code (just different filename. before the dtype change they both populated, but after, only one does. (one near the beginning which populates, and another at the end of the file which just gives an empty [] string ) . data.to_json('new_short.json',orient='records',date_format='iso')

Comment: @user3120554 Hard to say without data, but I'd recommend doing `df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(open('new_short.json').read())` and see what that does.

Comment: i get the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @user3120554 Then, `df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json.load(open('new_short.json')))` is what I can suggest.

Comment: i have an example one below for one record, this has the id from the original json: [{"id_str": "823962574509248514", "created_at": "Tue Jan 24 18:36:00 +0000 2017", "full_text": "@ABC Can I send a DM, I've emailed twice and got no response or can you give me an email address please?", "in_reply_to_status_id": null}]

Comment: @user3120554 Thanks a bunch, that was very helpful of you. See my edit please.

Comment: i couldnt get the normalize code working. Although i think i resolved my issue for why one of the output jsons was empty. dtype=str has a weird impact on looking for empty cells for a column which messed up my code (pandas previously used float dtype instead of object. Once i explicitly specify the id field as str only dtype={'id_str':str} then it seems to have started working.  Thanks for your help!